# Как растягивать background на Андроиде?

Tags: android, android-layout

Рассмотрим то, что мне нужно, на примере этого котика:

[image: котик оригинал]

Допустим, в моём приложении этот котик представляет собой атрибут `background` в корневом `layout` в файле `main_activity.xml`.

Во-первых, если экран устройства меньше, чем котик, то котик должен сжиматься, но никак не обрезаться. **Причём так, чтоб на экране не оставалось пустого места**. То есть:

[image: котик не хочет остаться без головы]

Так-то оно и по умолчанию происходит, но есть одно больше во-вторых: все view-элементы на экране тоже должны сжиматься и оставаться на той части котика, на которой они были изначально, то есть:

[image: view-элементы не должны убегать от котика]

В общем, это всё, что мне нужно, но так должно быть **на каждом устройстве**, учитывая планшеты.

Я много читал в интернете про все эти экранные дела, но там нету целостной картины. А мне нужна **полная последовательность действий**:

- какие нужно создавать `layout`'ы?
- какие к ним нужны подпапки `drawable`?
- какого разрешения делать котиков?
- писать ли что-то в `AndroidManifest`?
- и что-то ещё, чего я не знаю..?

Comment: имхо, ваши incorrect на самом деле correct. Вы в браузере, например, где-нить видели, чтоб при изменении размеров окна все сжималось, в том числе шрифты? Если вам нужны искажения, боюсь, придется все это рисовать в битмап и отображать как искаженную картинку, ну то есть свой движок писать... Верстка должна быть адаптивной.

Comment: @YuraIvanov , но ведь есть несколько density типов экранов (mdpi, hdpi, xhpdi, xxhdpi), и на офф сайте android целая [статья](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), про density independence, где на [скриншоте](https://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/density-test-good.png) показан как раз тот результат, что мне нужен. Я просто совсем не понимаю, как они этого добились. И каждое нормальное android приложение одинаково выглядит на всех устройствах. **Как решают эту проблему профессионалы?**

Comment: Вы путаете плотность и габариты. Там показано, что на телефонах с разными плотностями картинки будут отображаться одинаково если в соответствующие папочки разложить соответствующих размеров изображения. Никакого отношения к искажению и тем более других view это не имеет.

Comment: @YuraIvanov , да, плотность, по большому счёту я это и имел в виду! ведь основных типов соотношения сторон всего два, и если создать xml файл c bitmap'ом из котика, то пожертвовать придётся всего краешком ушка. Напишите, пожалуйста, ответ про поддержку всех плотностей экрана, в том числе и планшетных!

Comment: Вряд ли у меня получится лучше, и притом кратко, чем на соответствующих сайтах. Есть startandroid.ru например, почитайте там. Кроме того вопрос не соответствует тому, что вы просите рассказать...

Comment: @YuraIvanov , дак не, я то и имел в виду, просто про слово "плотность" забыл. Можете хоть ссылочку, пожалуйста? Просто русских статей я не нашёл, а на английском не понятно совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Требуемого вами поведения можно в основном добиться, используя следующую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/kotic"
>
<View
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:text="This is TextView"/>
<View
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"/></LinearLayout>
```

Котик заполняет собой все место - и в альбомной и в портретной ориентации. Проверено на телефоне и планшете. Надпись распологается на одном и том же месте котика.

Если искать несоответстие, то это не совсем пропорциональное изменение размера текста (особенно заметно по ширине). Тут конечно тоже можно было бы повозиться и пересчитать размер шрифта, исходя из числа пикселей экрана. И назначить этот размер шрифта программно. Но мне кажется, не стоит так напрягаться, так как результат вполне сносный. Если лезть в такие дебри, то потом возникнут проблемы типа: а что если текст не поместится в одну строку? и т.д.

По поводу разных плотностей. Картинка благополучно растянулась под размер экрана и на телефоне и на планшете. Оба устройства с нормальной плотностью. Для высокой плотности неплохо было бы предоставить картинку побольше. Для низкой плотности - поменьше, чтобы занимала меньше места, и не было артефактов изображения при обработке слишком детализированного изображения для экрана, где мало пикселей, хотя, может, это и лишнее.